# Sorting a nested OrderedDict by key, recursively

Tags: python, sorting, recursion, ordereddictionary

Say `orig` is an `OrderedDict` which contains normal string:string key value pairs, but sometimes the value could be another, nested `OrderedDict`.

I want to sort `orig` by key, alphabetically (ascending), and do it *recursively*.

Rules:

- Assume key strings are unpredictable
- Assume nesting can take place infinitely, e.g. level 1-50 all have both strings, OrderedDicts, etc as values.

Need an assist with the `sorted` algorithm:

```
import string
from random import choice


orig = OrderedDict((
    ('a', choice(string.digits)),
    ('b', choice(string.digits)),
    ('c', choice(string.digits)),
    ('special', OrderedDict((
        ('a', choice(string.digits)),
        ('b', choice(string.digits)),
        ('c', choice(string.digits)),
    )))
))

sorted_copy = OrderedDict(sorted(orig.iteritems(), ...))

self.assertEqual(orig, sorted_copy)
```

Comment: Is it only a single level deep? Or the `OrderedDict` corresponding to `special` could have another `OrderedDict` inside it?

Comment: @SukritKalra I added a `Rules` section to the question that will hopefully lead to a solution that can be repurposed without special knowledge of the OrderedDict structure.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski needed it for safely creating checksums of dicts that contain lots of different nested data types. Little things like dict key order were altering the checksum, even though the contents of the dict had not technically changed. Sorting these keys before quickly calculating the dict's hash with `hashlib.md5(str(my_dict).hexdigest()` allowed me to safely compare future versions. (The REAL reason is MongoDB doesn't guarantee object order per: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-limitations). TLDR: ... long story

Answer (score 23, accepted):

@acushner's solution can now be simplified in python3.6+ as dictionaries now preserve their insertion order.

Given we can now use the standard dictionary, the code now looks like:

```
def order_dict(dictionary):
    result = {}
    for k, v in sorted(dictionary.items()):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            result[k] = order_dict(v)
        else:
            result[k] = v
    return result
```

Because we can use standard dictionaries, we can also use standard dictionary comprehensions, so the code boils down to:

```
def order_dict(dictionary):
    return {k: order_dict(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v
            for k, v in sorted(dictionary.items())}
```

See also https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2016-September/146327.html for detail on python's ordered dictionary implementation. Also, the pronouncement that this will be a language feature as of python 3.7: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2017-December/151283.html

Answer (score 24):

EDIT: for python 3.6+, @pelson's answer is better

something like:

```
def sortOD(od):
    res = OrderedDict()
    for k, v in sorted(od.items()):
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            res[k] = sortOD(v)
        else:
            res[k] = v
    return res
```

Answer (score 10):

I faced a very similar issue with getting a stable object so I could get a stable hash, except I had objects with a mix of lists and dictionaries, so I had to sort all the dictionaries, depth first, and then sort the lists. This extends [@acushner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129600/acushner)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22721724/271351):

```py
def deep_sort(obj):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        obj = OrderedDict(sorted(obj.items()))
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict) or isinstance(v, list):
                obj[k] = deep_sort(v)

    if isinstance(obj, list):
        for i, v in enumerate(obj):
            if isinstance(v, dict) or isinstance(v, list):
                obj[i] = deep_sort(v)
        obj = sorted(obj, key=lambda x: json.dumps(x))

    return obj
```

As a side point, if you find yourself with classes in your objects that you need to sort, you can `jsonpickle.dumps()` them, then `json.loads()` them, then `deep_sort()` them. If it matters, then you can always `json.dumps()` and `jsonpickle.loads()` to get back to where you started, except sorted (well, only sorted in Python 3.6+). For cases of a stable hash, that wouldn't be necessary though.

Answer (score 5):

Very similar to @acushner's solution, but class-based:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


class SortedDict(OrderedDict):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SortedDict, self).__init__()

        for key, value in sorted(kwargs.items()):
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                self[key] = SortedDict(**value)
            else:
                self[key] = value
```

Usage:

```
sorted_dict = SortedDict(**unsorted_dict)
```

Comment: nice. Extra credit if it remains sorted when inserting extra values OR when calling `my_sorted_dict.sort()`

Comment: This can be achieved by overriding your iterator of choice (or all of them):
    def items(self):
        for key, value in sorted(self.keys()):
            yield key, value

The items in the dictionary will be sorted on read instead of on insert.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of [@pelson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47882384/99377) and [@cjbarth's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218649/99377), with `key` and `reverse` parameters:

```py
def deep_sorted(obj, *, key=None, reverse=False):
    if isinstance(obj, dict):
        return {k: deep_sorted(v, key=key, reverse=reverse) for k, v in sorted(obj.items(), key=key, reverse=reverse)}
    if isinstance(obj, list):
        return [deep_sorted(v, key=key, reverse=reverse) for i, v in sorted(enumerate(obj), key=key, reverse=reverse)]
    return obj
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're still living in py2...like me....this is the 3.6+ version with lambda to pre-sort the keys.

```
    def __sort_od(od):
        res = OrderedDict()
        for k, v in sorted(od.items(), key=lambda k: k[0]):
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                res[k] = __sort_od(v)
            else:
                res[k] = v
        return res
    sorted_OrderedDict = __sort_od(unsorted_dict)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).