# How can you sort an multiple layer list alphabetically with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, list

I am trying to order a multiple layer list. the problem I ran into was that the sublist merged  with mine main list and this is not the intention.
the code that I used.

```js
$('#test').click(function(e) {
    $(".first ul").each(function() {
        $(this).find('li').sort(function(a, b) {
            var aText = $(a).text(),
            bText = $(b).text();
            return aText < bText ? -1 : aText > bText ? 1 : 0;
        }).appendTo(this);
    });  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-2-12" id="menu-mappen">
         <ul class="first sortable-folder">
          <li class="active"><a id="id1" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Afbeeldingen</a></li>
          <li><a id="id2" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Producten</a></li>
          <li><a id="id3" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Homepage</a></li>
          <li class="has-children"><a id="id4" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Bestanden</a>
            <ul class="first sortable-folder">
              <li><a id="id5" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Afbeeldingen</a></li>
              <li><a id="id6" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Producten</a></li>
              <li class="has-children"><a id="id4" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Bestanden</a>
                <ul class=" first sortable-folder">
                  <li><a id="id5" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Afbeeldingen</a></li>
                  <li><a id="id6" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Producten</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a id="id7" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Afbeeldingen</a></li>
        </ul>
        <button id="test"></button>

      </div>
```

I hope that someone can help me with this.

Comment: It looks like you are grabbing all of the `li` elements, not just the ones on a specific "layer". You could do a recursive sort?

Comment: Do you have a sample of a recursive sort?

Comment: [Here is a python example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22721579/sorting-a-nested-ordereddict-by-key-recursively?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa). Though I agree with Gabriele Petrioli's answer. Your query method was flawed. Resolving that is probably a more straight forward method than recursive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `$(this).find('li')` to `$(this).children('li')`

This way each sort will be applied to sibling `li` elements.

```js
$('#test').click(function(e) {
  $(".first ul").each(function() {
    $(this).children('li').sort(function(a, b) {
      var aText = $(a).text(),
        bText = $(b).text();
      return aText < bText ? -1 : aText > bText ? 1 : 0;
    }).appendTo(this);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-2-12" id="menu-mappen">
  <ul class="first sortable-folder">
    <li class="active"><a id="id1" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Afbeeldingen</a></li>
    <li><a id="id2" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Producten</a></li>
    <li><a id="id3" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Homepage</a></li>
    <li class="has-children"><a id="id4" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Bestanden</a>
      <ul class="first sortable-folder">
        <li><a id="id5" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Afbeeldingen</a></li>
        <li><a id="id6" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Producten</a></li>
        <li class="has-children"><a id="id4" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Bestanden</a>
          <ul class=" first sortable-folder">
            <li><a id="id5" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Afbeeldingen</a></li>
            <li><a id="id6" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Producten</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a id="id7" href="#"><i class="far fa-folder"></i>Afbeeldingen</a></li>
  </ul>
  <button id="test"></button>

</div>
```